# cellForRowAtIndexPath: for StoryBoard and XIB Behaviour and Cell caching mechanism?

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview

I am new in iOS Development. I do not understand behaviour of tableView.

To test it, I have made two Simple tableView application and I have loaded tableView with 99999 rows with standard code snippet in both cases , if user scrolls down till the end of tableView.

**App 1 : TableViewWithStoryBoard cellForRowAtIndexPath: code snippet**

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
static NSString *CellIdentifier = @"Cell";

UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier forIndexPath:indexPath]; // for StoryBoard

if (cell == nil)
{
    static int i;
    NSLog(@"New Cells created: %d ",++i);    

  cell = [[UITableViewCell alloc]initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier:CellIdentifier];
}

// Configure the cell...

cell.textLabel.text = [self.tableData objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];

return cell;
```

}

**Question 1:** 
If I remove

```
forIndexPath:indexPath from 
UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier forIndexPath:indexPath]; // for StoryBoard
```

then StoryBoard still functions properly in simulator? 
Then why it has been provided ?

**Question 2:**
Why NSLog(@"New Cells created: %d ",++i); never gets printed even if i scroll down to 99999 rows that is end of my tableView? In what scenario NSLog will print some values ?

**App 2: TableViewWithNib cellForRowAtIndexPath: code snippet**

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
static NSString *CellIdentifier = @"Cell";

UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier];
// for Nib File

if (cell == nil)
{

    cell = [[UITableViewCell alloc]initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier:CellIdentifier];
}

// Configure the cell...

cell.textLabel.text = [self.tableData objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];

return cell;
```

}

**Question 3:**
If I add

```
forIndexPath:indexPath
```

in the XIB Version then my application crashes and throws an Exception? Why is it so ? 


Exception or Error:
     Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInternalInconsistencyException', reason:  'unable to dequeue a cell with identifier Cell - must register a nib or a class for the identifier or connect a prototype cell in a storyboard'

Comment: The code is a bit unclear, can you put this it all together?

Comment: @jcesar - Hey I have put all code together and also mentioned code part which are in question.I have made SingleView Based App1 with StoryBoard and SingleView Based App2 with Nib

Answer (score 0):

**Question 2:** The `NSLog` is printed the first time when it creates the first rows (I have tested with a sample project and was printed 24 times o iPad), the rest of the times it isn't printed because the cells already exist and reuse them.

**Questions 1&3:** The `forIndexPath:indexPath` in the `dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier` is new in iOS 6, you must register a cell `xib` or a custom `UITableViewCell` class for the identifier or connect a prototype cell in a storyboard to use it.

Comment: I have tested even on iPad Simulator as well NSLog(@"New Cells created: %d ",++i); is in the block if(cell == nil){ NSLog....}. This block never gets called on iPhone or iPad based application. I have tested by loading by 99999 rows.Even i have scrolled up and down several times.So my question is when does new cells are created.If tableView keeps on using existing cells.

Comment: NSLog will gets printed 23+2times on iPad and 9+2 on iPhone approx. logic is (visible cells + 2) that will happen only if put this two statements  static int i; NSLog(@"New Cells created: %d ",++i); just above return cell;

Comment: Tableview only create visible cells + 2, then reuse them, so it doesn't create more cells